# inherits option strict

Tags: vb.net, inheritance

I got an object(myObject) type Object. myObject inherits of another class that contain a fonction (ImyFunction). I want to call the function, but my project need to be in "Option Strict On". So it ask for declaration of the object.

```
Public MustInherit Class IClass(Of T1)
...
    Public Sub IMyFunction()
    ...


Public Class myClass1 : Inherits IClass(Of Item1)
...
Public Class myClass2 : Inherits IClass(Of Item2)




dim obj as object = new myClass1
...
obj.IMyFunction 'at this moment, I dont know whish class base of IClass I have
```

(its just a sample)

I cant do obj.IMyFunction because of the strict option.
Maybe there's a cast way?

Comment: Why do you box it as `Object`? Just  declare it as `myClass` or `IClass`.

Comment: Its an MustInherit so I cant use as type. and in the situation I need it, it can be any class base on IClass.

Comment: It’s unclear what you’re asking but this code is simply invalid and of course VB complains. But `Option Strict` has got nothing to do with it. It wouldn’t work anyway.

Comment: Just as an aside, normal .net naming conventions dictate that a class name should not start with an I as that usually denotes an interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MustInherit` keyword does not mean that you cannot use it as a variable type, it just means that you cannot instantiate it.  For instance:

```
Dim obj As IClass(Of Item1) = New myClass1()  ' This works
Dim obj2 As IClass(Of Item1) = New IClass(Of Item1)()  ' This will not compile
```

However since, it's generic, you have to specify the type of `T1`, so there's no way to do what I think it is that you really want to do:

```
Dim obj As IClass = New myClass1()  ' Can't do this
obj.iMyFunction()
```

What I would recommend, in this case, would be to make either a non-generic base class or interface, like this:

```
Public Interface IInterface
    Sub IMyFunction()
End Interface

Public MustInherit Class IClass(Of T1)
    Implements IInterface
End Class
```

Then, you could do something like this:

```
Dim obj As IInterface = New myClass1()
obj.IMyFunction()
```

Comment: tank you steven, it work. Finaly a reason to use interface :)